Turning pdf pages into bitmap with original size
I am turnın pdf pages into bitmap and displaying them in a recyclerview but there is a problem original pdf bitmaps have the size of 841*595 but if a render the bitmaps with this size bitmaps looks too bad thus ı have to render them 1920*1080 but this increases the final file size
 private void pdfToBitmaps(Uri pdfUri) {
        // Use a background thread to process the PDF
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executor.execute(() -> {
            try {
                ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(pdfUri, "r");
                PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer(parcelFileDescriptor);
                int initailcount = renderer.getPageCount();

                if (parcelFileDescriptor != null && initailcount < 600) {
                    int pageCount = renderer.getPageCount();
                    Log.d("PdfToBitmaps", "Total pages: " + pageCount);

                    for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++) {
                        PdfRenderer.Page page = renderer.openPage(i);
                        Log.d("PdfToBitmaps", "Rendering page: " + i);
                       


                        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1080, 1920, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
                        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                        page.render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
                      
                        mlkitforembededtext(bitmap,i);
                        // Add bitmap to list and notify adapter
                        runOnUiThread(() -> {
                            pdfBitmaps.add(bitmap);
                            pdfAdapter.notifyItemInserted(pdfBitmaps.size() - 1);
                        });


       
                        page.close();
                    }
                    renderer.close();
}

this is the code ı use to turn pages into bitmap
how can ı render the pages with original size and have a good bitmap quality

Thank you for informative comment at least now ı know ı am not doing anything wrong but how should keep the file size while saving? Should ı find a compress method?

Why do you create an ARGB image? The A stand for alpha transparency but usually PDF files have  a solid background thus alpha transparency is not used. Creating a simply RGB PNG file would decrease each pixel from 4 byte to 3 byte (in memory, not sure how large the effect on the PNG file is). In addition if there are no images in the PDF or image quality is not so important you could reduce the number of colors which would increase compression rate of PNG.

Actually i tried to render the pdf file with rgb_565 but when i try to do this the app crushes any idea why?

When you render them to a bitmap choose any factor to scale them at.
e.g. render 841 x 595 as 1628 x 1190 which is a factor of 2
When you display them scale them down by the inverse of the scale factor
e.g a scale factor of 1/2 (0.5)
Currently you are changing the aspect ratio from ~1.4 (standard for A4 paper) to ~1.78 thus the image will be stretched or squished in one of the dimensions and making it look horrible.
You don't show the drawing of the bitmap in the recyclerview so there are a number of ways to set the scale factor when drawing.
e.g.
canvas.scale(0.5,0.5);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, left, top, paint);


or
Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
scaleMatrix.setScale(0.5);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, scaleMatrix, paint);


or there are various canvas.drawBitmap methods with rectangle sizes the will cause it to scale the bitmap down
you can also do paint.setAntiAlias(true);
to help improve the look

Fixed italics, thanks. The horrible look is probably because they are changing the aspect ratio from ~1.4 (standard for A4 paper) to ~1.78 thus the image will be stretch or squished in one of the dimensions.
